# Understanding JDBC & MySQL procedure to store a JAVA ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

first post ! (i've read a lot though)

I have a 8 week school project and the point is to program a Draw Something-Like (kind of Pictionary).

What is the clean way to store a Java ArrayList to a MySQL database ?

We have to store the drawings into a MySQL database because it's one of the project's requirements.
We decided to associate the Drawings to an ArrayList containing [X,Y] positions of all the clicked points in order to draw it back when someone has to Guess what the word is.

I have trouble to understand what is the clean way to store an ArrayList into MySQL, the problem being that i have seen so many ways on google, and the posts are between 2007-2013, i don't know what's good and what's not.

Sorry i hope it's clear i'm french i tried my best.

Regards,

Comment: show us what you have in your mind and where exactly you look for enhancement

Comment: An `ArrayList` is an ordered set of objects. An object is (essentially) an ordered set of values. A table is an **un**ordered set of rows. A table row is an ordered set of values. See the pattern?

Comment: I think i get it tell me if i'm wrong. I have to store every coordinate in a row or in rows ? I can create a new Table "Coordinates" linked too a drawing
But i'll need at least a tinyint (2 bytes)for each x/y coordinate which means thousands of them for each drawing . Is it not too heavy ?

Comment: A thousand drawings with a thousand points requires... 2MB :) Don't worry, it will fit. Remember that rows in a table are *not* ordered.

Comment: What do you think of this ?
A Table Drawing (Author, Date, Rating, Etc) linked to many tables Coordinates (index, x, y) and use index to draw back in the right order ?
At this point i am not sure i really need ArrayList, i just need to read the database and draw as i read it. Correct ?